# How to scroll 'n' lines in vi?

Tags: vi

Say you are scanning a huge log and `CTRL-F` simply does not cut it. Can you move down predefined number of lines, say 500? How would you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

type `500j`

j moves one line down, and as usual you can repeat a command N times by a numeric prefix